# Drupal Multilingual translating views Argument

Tags: drupal, internationalization, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I am working on a multi lingual site using i18n module in Drupal 6 Version.
I have created Taxonomy terms per langauge and created mapping for the two languages I am using.
Now i created a page view(URL collections/%) with taxonomy term as views argument, for listing the nodes related to that term id.

Now the problem is when I view the url collections/4 in English its listing all the nodes related to that term id .
But when I click on the language Switcher the url become fr/collections/4 instead of fr/collections/20 where 20 is the translated term id for term id 4.

Please help me in solving this issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a filter for language as well! That will do the job!

Comment: I have added Filter for language. But still its not solving my problem.

Comment: what values you have selected for the filter? If you do not get the data/content, that means content are not in particular langauge. Check you 'Content' page as well!